# BeautifulSoup how to write an XML file with utf-8

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi I would like to create a xml document that contains some french alphabet in the content. The xml tag that I did modify (by script) have the correct output in the new xml file (the one I create) but all the xml tag **that I didn't modified** have some unexpected characters.

```
#Open file
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('example2.xml'),'xml')

#...
# code that update (modify) some xml element value
#....

#write to a file
def create_a_file(content, filename = 'hello.xml'):
    f = open(filename, "w")
    f.write(str(content))
    f.close()


#.. output of the file
# I modify this tag with a script and it displays well 
<subTitl>Enquête sur le web, juillet 2010</subTitl>
# I didn't modify either the tag or the attribute but it doesn't display properly
<AuthEnty university="UniversitÃ© Montpellier. Centre gÃ©ographique, statistique">
          Ã©sir, Pras
        </AuthEnty>
```

As you see I didn't modify the XML element named AuthEnty but I have some unexpected characters.

Question
How can I write properly this document. Is it on the opening that the file wasn't properly parse?

Answer (score 0):

Importing codecs works.

```
#Open file
import codecs 
f = codecs.open('example2.xml','r','utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"xml")
f.close()
```

This will display the correct output when I write create a xml file.